# How to be with the update_all method after the last method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-6

If write the following code:

```rb
User.last(5).update_all(smth: true)
```

Then the expected error will come in response:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `update_all' for #<Array:0x00007fd74b25a290>)
```

But what should I do if I need to get the last N records and update all of them?

I have a list (`User.all`). From this list, the first M entries I can not touch. That is, I need to update these entries:

```rb
n = User.count - m
User.last(n).update_all(smth: true)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only want to update last `n` records, you can use `order` with `limit`:

```
User.order(created_at: :desc).limit(n).update_all(smth: true)
```

In your specific case though, i.e. if you want to update all records apart from first `m`, there's even better suited way with SQL `offset` which exactly fits your need:

```
User.order(created_at: :asc).offset(m).update_all(smth: true)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I updated the question text. Do you think your answer is suitable for what I added at the end?

Comment: @Colibri yes, but for this specific case, there's an even better approach, with `offset`, check my edited answer.

Comment: Understood. Thanks you.